# Find <iframe> width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an object like this:

```
object = {
    iframe: "<iframe width="560" height="315" src="YouTube link"></iframe>"
}
```

I need to take the width (in this case 560) and height (in this case 315) value inside this  with jQuery/js. Because I need to use this value.

Is that possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Is `object.iframe` in your example a string, or an Element, or a jQuery object..? It's not clear

Comment: Note: the string is invalid - the quotes inside the string are not being escaped. Escape them with backslashes (`\"`) or use different types of quotes

Comment: Hi @RoryMcCrossan, yes, the string is object.iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to isolate the two parameters:

```js
var object = {
    iframe: '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="YouTube link"></iframe>' // string was invalid before, replaced quotes with apostrophes
}
var regexFound = object.iframe.match(/width="(\d*?)" height="(\d*?)"/);
var asArray = [regexFound[1], regexFound[2]];
var asObject = {width: regexFound[1], height: regexFound[2]}
console.log(asArray, asObject);
```

Comment: Thank you Lemondoge! That is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly note that the string in the example is invalid due to the repeated use of `"`. To make the string valid, delimit it with `'` and use `"` to contain the attribute values within it.

As you've tagged the question with jQuery you can use that to build an object from the string instead of parsing it using regex:

```js
let object = {
  iframe: '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="YouTube link"></iframe>'
}

let $iframe = $(object.iframe);

console.log($iframe.prop('width'));
console.log($iframe.prop('height'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Rory! Nice jQuery solution.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Just be aware that parsing HTML using regex is incredibly bad practice, and can cause other issues.

Comment: Thanks for the info Rory, I have appreciated. I'm never stop learning.